# Install CentOS 5.6 packages on 5.7?

Tags: centos

How safe is it to install CentOS 5.6 packages on 5.7? Assume its not just one package, but trying out 5.6 repo on 5.7 server. Just asking out of curiosity.

I think it breaks a lot if its precise and trusty but not much on centos versions?

Comment: Please provide the use case. Why would would want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it won't brake anything, because your installed packages are already at higher version than those in 5.6 feature level repo.

New packages will either install fine or refuse to install because of conflict with some already installed newer version package.

The problem may appear in case you decide to use `yum downgrade`. Then you'd probably enter the dependency hell...

And the last thing. Why don't you use repo with recent versions?

Comment: I have 5.6 local repo setup and working on setting up 5.7 but I had to ask the question just so I'd know about it. Thanks for the answer